# XPages Time Edit Box - Set start time

Tags: time, xpages

It seems that since Fixpack 6 our edit boxes für setting a time value have changed a bit. If I use the time picker pop-up the selection always starts with 0:00. How can I set the first time to e.g. 8:00?

Could not see any option to set the start time in the properties list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My best guess (without having FP6 currently at hand) is that it may have moved to a newer version of the TimeTextBox?

Looking at this ticket it seems that the previously used 'visibleRange' property of the constraints has been made obsolete by a new combination of 'pickerMin' and 'pickerMax' properties.
https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/18220

The Extension library's 'constraints' complex property (xe:djDateTimeConstraints) has not been upgraded to support these new properties.
Although the Extension Library provides the 'XPages Control' for the Dojo Time Picker, it uses the dijit javascript files from the core domino dojo plugin, thus explaining why one might be upgraded without the other knowing about it.

While you wait for the ExtLib to be updated, perhaps there is a way to get a hold of the TimeTextBox 'dijit' and add the constraints programmatically after the dijit has been initialised.

something like this (note: I have not tested) in some sort of after page load event

```
dijit.byId('yourdijitsid').constraints.pickerMin = "T08:00:00"; 
dijit.byId('yourdijitsid').constraints.pickerMax = "T18:00:00";
```

Comment: But it wouldn't be possible to enter time outside of that range, right?

Comment: Yeah I haven't tested, but I would suppose it limits the input to that range.
I couldn't see any other options but maybe there is another creative way to do it that I am not thinking of

Comment: I've put this code in the onClientLoad event, but it doesn't change the selection. It still starts with 0:00

Comment: do any errors show in the browser console when attempt to set these properties on the dijit? are you confident that the properties were set sucessfully on the dijit and they had no effect? or were they not set properly
i'll see if I can get my hands on FP6 and run a test myself